Is it possible to bench same function with different features in rust?
How can I run (if possible) a benchmark (I'm using divan currently, but open to suggestions) of the same function with a feature enable and disabled?
use divan::counter::ItemsCount;
use divan::{black_box, counter::BytesCount, AllocProfiler, Bencher};

fn main() {
    divan::main()
}

#[cfg(parallel)]
use rayon::iter::ParallelIterator;

fn compute_foo(size: usize) -> usize {
    #[cfg(parallel)]
    {
        (0..size).into_par_iter()
    }
    #[cfg(not(parallel))]
    { (0..size).into_iter() }.map(|i| i * 123 / 4).sum()
}

#[divan::bench(args = [16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096])]
fn commit_single_polynomial_with_element_count(bencher: Bencher, size: usize) {
    bencher
        .input_counter(|| ItemsCount::new(size))
        .bench_refs(|| black_box(compute_foo(size)));
}


If you are following the rule that features must be additive, then just enable the feature and pass it as a runtime flag to the function you're testing (so here e.g. fn compute_foo(size: usize, use_parallel_feature : bool) -> usize).

@user2407038, the feature enables or disables rayon. It is not meant to be used in runtime but in compilation time.
